# Pass multiple values for one parameter in a web form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a form where I need to pass multiple child ages in one query and the parameter name is the same.

I need the below up to 6 times.

```
<label for="childages">Children: </label>
                                     <select name="childages">
                                     <option value="0">0</option>
                                     <option value="1">1</option>
                                     <option value="2">2</option>
                                     <option value="3">3</option>
                                     <option value="4">4</option>
                                     <option value="5">5</option>
                                     </select>
```

When I do this the values return like:

&childages=1,2,3

The problem with the above is that the system only reads the first number.

I need them to return as:

&childages=1|2|3

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Who passes the values to you in query???? What code you've tried. Show us some code and we will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the URL, try this:

```
window.location.search = window.location.search + '&childages=1|2|3';
```

Modify this and add conditions as you wish.

Otherwise you can construct a FormData() and do the following:

```
formData.append('childages', '1|2|3');
```

and post it to the endpoint.